# Problems with option text not showing in Medium editor (from Github)

Tags: javascript, jquery, medium-editor

As you see in the attachment below, some option buttons are not shown correctly. Some of the buttons are missing out the text/icon, however they work correctly as they should.

[image]

I implemented it inside a web page, not on a blank page.
Can it be CSS interference?

Suggestions?

The plugin is available here
https://github.com/orthes/medium-editor

Answer (score 0):

I see, that you downloaded the editor, from my old fork, not from official repo here: https://github.com/daviferreira/medium-editor

Try to download it from there, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest version of the repo, this should no longer be an issue.

If it is still an issue, this can be resolved by running a small node server to serve up the demo page instead of navigating straight to a file-path in your browser.

If you clone the latest version of the repo from [github](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor) just navigate to the root directory and run the following:

```
npm install
node index.js
```

npm install will install all the basic dev dependencies, which include `connect` and `serve-static`.  These 2 libraries are used to create a simple static webserver that is invoked when you run `index.js`.

You can the navigate to `http://localhost:8088/demo/index.html` and you should now be able to access all the demos and the toolbar icons should display properly.